# I add a fee to my Woocommerce cart but when i load the checkout page i can't see the fee and the total updated

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce web running and i use ajax requests to add, delete and empty the cart of woocommerce. The thing is i have this ajax called in my server site (php).

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once "../../wp-load.php";
global $wpdb;
global $woocommerce;

// Saneamos importe por post
$fee = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fee', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
$fee = floatval($fee);

$woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Montaje', $importe);

// Obtén el contenido del carrito actualizado
$cart_content = array(
    'products' => $woocommerce->cart->get_cart(),
    'fees' => $woocommerce->cart->get_fees()
);

echo json_encode($cart_content);
```

The response is correct cause is this:

```
{"products":{"36ad8b5f42db492827016448975cc22d":{"key":"36ad8b5f42db492827016448975cc22d","product_id":7763,"variation_id":0,"variation":[],"quantity":1,"data_hash":"b5c1d5ca8bae6d4896cf1807cdf763f0","line_tax_data":{"subtotal":[],"total":[]},"line_subtotal":100,"line_subtotal_tax":0,"line_total":100,"line_tax":0,"data":{}},"f968fdc88852a4a3a27a81fe3f57bfc5":{"key":"f968fdc88852a4a3a27a81fe3f57bfc5","product_id":5259,"variation_id":0,"variation":[],"quantity":1,"data_hash":"b5c1d5ca8bae6d4896cf1807cdf763f0","line_tax_data":{"subtotal":{"1":106.0499999999999971578290569595992565155029296875},"total":{"1":106.0499999999999971578290569595992565155029296875}},"line_subtotal":505,"line_subtotal_tax":106.0499999999999971578290569595992565155029296875,"line_total":505,"line_tax":106.0499999999999971578290569595992565155029296875,"data":{}}},"fees":{"montaje":{"id":"montaje","name":"Montaje","tax_class":"","taxable":false,"amount":"0","total":0}}}
```

Where you can see the products and the fee. But when i load the checkout page to fill the payment data, and see the order it doesn't appear the fee and the updated total. I tried to apply a calculate_totals() to the cart but if i do this it returns me the fee empty.

Anyone know what is going on and can help me? Thanks!

I tried to add different fees, calculate the totals of the cart and debug everything but the result is the same, only products on my cart.